# How to customize materialize chips when created?

Tags: javascript, materialize

I am using materialize css framework and I am currently using `chips` component.

Code is below

```
 <div class="chips chips-initial"></div>
```

Now as per the documentation guide I am initializing chip object.

```
<script>
 $('.chips-initial').material_chip({
                data: [{
                    tag: 'Apple',
                }, {
                    tag: 'Microsoft',
                }, {
                    tag: 'Google',
                }],
 });
</script>
```

Everything works fine but I want to know how we can show close button or custom image (contact-chip) when chip is created in textbox.Currently it shows 'close' text to close that chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included Material Icons?

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: No.It was missing.Thanks.

Comment: I have this issue too, but I want want to use fontawesome 4.7 instead of Material Icons. How can I?